# ng-init miscalculates aliased index after array.splice

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

I have encountered a strange behavior related to ng-init, any help would be appreciated.

I have a model object which has a flats property that is an array of flat objects. Each flat object has rooms property which is an array of room objects.

I'm trying to display flat and rooms as follows;

```
<table ng-repeat="flat in model.flats" ng-init="flatIndex = $index">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>{{flatIndex+1}}. {{flat.name}}</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="room in flat.rooms" ng-init="roomIndex = $index">
    <td>{{roomIndex+1}}. {{room.name}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If i delete a flat or room by using `array.splice` `flatIndex` and `roomIndex` variables doesn't seem to update properly even though `$index` and ui updates properly.

You can see the problem [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QKeN9635W3mUf5P6l07W?p=preview) in action.

Try to delete 1st, 2nd or 3rd flat or room object by clicking the delete link. Deleting last object from the array doesn't really expose the problem.

Any workarounds would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known behavior when you use `ng-init`, the scope property values set by `ng-init` are not watched and they don't update when you remove items from array to reflect the refreshed index position. So don't use `ng-init`, instead just use `$index` (`deleteFlat($index)`) and `flat` object reference (to get hold of rooms `deleteRoom(flat,$index)`).

```
<table ng-repeat="flat in model.flats track by flat.id">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">{{$index+1}}. {{flat.name}}</td>
        <td><a href="#" ng-click="deleteFlat($index)">DELETE FLAT</a></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="room in flat.rooms  track by room.id">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>{{$index+1}}. {{room.name}}</td>
        <td><a href="#" ng-click="deleteRoom(flat,$index)">DELETE ROOM</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and

```
$scope.deleteFlat = function(flatIndex){
    $scope.model.flats.splice(flatIndex,1);
};

$scope.deleteRoom = function(flat,roomIndex){
   flat.rooms.splice(roomIndex,1);
};
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CeL2Yv?p=preview)**

Or better off use the ids itself, `deleteFlat(flat.id)` and `deleteRoom(room.id, flat)`.

```
<table ng-repeat="flat in model.flats track by flat.id">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">{{$index + 1}}. {{flat.name}}</td>
        <td><a href="#" ng-click="deleteFlat(flat.id)">DELETE FLAT</a></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="room in flat.rooms track by room.id">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>{{$index+1}}. {{room.name}}</td>
        <td><a href="#" ng-click="deleteRoom(room.id, flat)">DELETE ROOM</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and

```
$scope.deleteFlat = function(flatId){
  $scope.model.flats.splice(_getItemIndex(flatId, $scope.model.flats), 1);
};

$scope.deleteRoom = function(roomId, flat){
  flat.rooms.splice(_getItemIndex(roomId, flat.rooms), 1);
};


function _getItemIndex(imtId, itms){
  var id ;
  itms.some(function(itm, idx){
      return (itm.id === imtId) && (id = idx)
   });
   return id;
}
```

**[Plnkr2](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Zk1Rj?p=preview)**

Comment: **[Here is shim for array.some for older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)**  You could just use a for loop as well.

Comment: I didn't know that ng-init variables are not watched. But i should have guessed that :) thank you for the answer. cheers.

Comment: @ysf You are welcome. :). Not just that, you could end up in similar issues when using filters as well.. So better try not to rely on `$index` especially when you have identifier.. :)